# Ошибка при выводе шорткода WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wp-plugin

Определяю в плагине:

```
function my_test_func() {
    $args = array(
        'post_type' => array('product'),
        'post_status' => array('publish'),
        'nopaging' => true,
    );
    $query = new WP_Query($args);
    print_r($query);
}
add_shortcode('my_test', 'my_test_func');
```

Затем в записи вывожу [my_test]

Открываю страницу записи и ловлю:

> 500 Internal server error Внутренняя ошибка

В чем может быть проблема?

Дебагинг включал, в лог ничего не вывелось.

Comment: Учить смотреть логи не буду, но что ты хочешь таким шорткодом  вывести?

Comment: Шорткод ничего не выведет даже в лучшем случае, потому что функция должна возвращать строку.

Comment: А 500 скорее всего потому, что товаров много, и на вывод всех требуется слишком много времени. Для отладки стоило бы убрать nopaging.